# Why does istream::read() not call streambuf::sgetn()?

Tags: c++, std

The function istream::read() must call either sgetc() or sbumpc() on its underlying streambuf object. This means that it necessarily extracts the characters one by one. Is there a reason for istream to be implemented this way or was it an arbitrary decission when making the standard?

The function ostream::write() in contrast is allowed to call either sputc() or sputn() on its underlying streambuf, which could make a performance difference.

Comment: Where are you getting this?  I checked the libc++ source and it does call `sgetn`.